# How do I show arrays in only one line

Tags: java

Firstly, excuse my English grammar due to i'm Spanish.
Well, I have this code:

```
public class practica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero = consola.nextInt();
        if (numero > 0 && numero <= 100) {
            int vector[] = new int[numero];

            for (int y = 0; y < numero; y++) {
                vector[y] = consola.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I had read numbers (by console) I must show them in only one line.
I know i must do it with `System.out.print();` but i don't know what i should type into the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public class practica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero = consola.nextInt();
        if (numero > 0 && numero <= 100) {
            List<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int y = 0; y < numero; y++) {
                vector.add(consola.nextInt());  
            }
            System.out.println(vector);
        }
    }
}
```

or this :

```
public class practica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero = consola.nextInt();
        if (numero > 0 && numero <= 100) {
            int vector[] = new int[numero];

            for (int y = 0; y < numero; y++) {
                vector[y] = consola.nextInt();  
                System.out.print(vector[y] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class practica {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero = consola.nextInt();
    if (numero > 0 && numero <= 100) {
        int[] vector = new int[numero];

        for (int y = 0; y < numero; y++) {
            vector[y] = consola.nextInt();
        }

        //look here
        for(int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++){
            System.out.print(vector[i] + ", ");
       }
    }
  }
```

}